# How to open each Wordpress post in new tab/window?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have one `wordpress` blog whose home page is showing a list of 10 latest posts.

Now whenever I am going to click on any post title, a new post will open in the same tab, but here I want to let open it in a new tab. So, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit your theme

```
/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/loop.php
```

look for post link eg...

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read_more_link" ><?php echo __('Read more &raquo;'
```

add `target="_blank"` attribute

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" class="read_more_link" ><?php echo __(
```

each Wordpress theme have a different html. just search for.. `href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"` this is permalink of each post

Comment: thanks yea my theme has no loop.php but the_permalink() was in index.php so i have just added target and its working fine. thanks

Answer (score 6):

There are different templates for each and every theme in Wordpress.

**Try finding**

```
    < a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"...............><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Press <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for this code like `the_title();`.
Normally these type of codes are founded in templates like

**single.php, content.php, loop.php, content-single.php**

Just add a `target="_blank"` in that code.

For example :

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank".....><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your relevant `php` file(s), ie. `front-page.php`, `home.php`... and just add `target="_blank"` in your title `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
I found this code on http://www.wpcodesnippet.com/open-external-links-new-window/ and it worked like a charm for me. Just add it to your footer.php.   

 <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('a').each(function() {
                var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
                if(!a.test(this.href)) {
                    $(this).click(function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        window.open(this.href, '_blank');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Hey! Can you update your answer to include the relevant code from your link, please? If that link breaks in the future, your answer will become useless.  Refer to section **Provide context for links** from http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

One convenient fix is to set the banner to open a new tab at the page after updating page at the notice: Page updated. **View page** link. Add the target="_blank" after the <a call.
At file /wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php change the line 136 as shown in the graphic. This was implemented at WordPress v4.9.8. When WP is updated the fix may need to be done again. 
[image: text editor view with added text highlighted]

Answer (score -1):

Unless your hosting it yourself I don't think you can, otherwise just change your links to:

```
<a href="your url" target="_blank">blah</a>
```

Comment: the file you need to edit is going to be **wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/loop-page.php** I think. It will be one of those loop pages.