# How to open Wordpress posts in new tab, scripting

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, post

I have wordpress website, and all posts are automatically added by another scripts. All posts are like this:

```
<p> 
<center> 
<!--videoplayer--><iframe src="http://embeds.sample.com/embed/123456" frameborder="0" width="720" height="550" scrolling="no"></iframe><!--endvideoplayer--> 
</center> 
</p><!--START-wtp-INFO - Do not remove these lines--><!--vidsource:sample.come.com--><!--vidcod:12345--><!--vidimage:http://sample2.com/wp-content/videoimages/2075/01/01/9999_sample2.jpg--><!--viddesc:--><!--END-wtp-INFO-->
```

There are tens of thousands of posts in my site. Its impossible to change every post manually. I think to make script which will add possibility all POSTS from main page to be oppened in new tab. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936909/how-to-open-each-wordpress-post-in-new-tab-window

Comment: nothing is working except this post i found and it worket http://stackoverflow.com/a/32640958/7159009