# WordPress post title link - open in new tab

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, blogs, title

I have a WordPress website and I have a section on my first page that shows the 6 recent blog posts. **I want those posts (and only those) to open in a new tab when clicked on the title**, i.e. I don't want to change the whole blog title attribute (or whatever it is called in WordPress).

I tried the answers in [how-to-open-each-wordpress-post-in-new-tab-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936909/how-to-open-each-wordpress-post-in-new-tab-window) but, I couldn't find anything like the code referenced there 
(`< a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"...............><?php the_title(); ?></a>`).

FYI, the loop.php had something that I thought would do the same thing for my theme, but even after adding `target="_blank"`, there was no change. The following is the part in loop.php that I changed:

```
<?php themify_post_before(); // hook ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_id(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'post clearfix' ); ?>>
<?php themify_post_start(); // hook ?>
<?php if($themify->unlink_title!='yes' || $themify->unlink_image!='yes'):?>
<a href="<?php echo themify_get_featured_image_link(); ?>" data-post-permalink="yes" style="display: none;" target="_blank"></a>
<?php endif;?>
```

**Can someone please help me with this?**

Comment: Can you give us your PHP code ?

Comment: Edit your question and post your code there.

Comment: In you code I see style="display: none;" in the link and the content of the anchor tag is empty. Are you sure you are clicking on the link from that code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not! But, it was the only code snippet in the theme files that had anything to do with the posts, or at least the only one I found!

Comment: Maybe there is a JS with preventDefault() for links?

Comment: I searched through the theme files using the String Locator plugin and I found a lot of `preventDefault()`s. But, looking into the files, I couldn't figure out if any of them were directly related to the links, especially the links that are present in the blog titles in the home page, as I can override other links in the Builder or the post itself to be opened in a new tab.